# Reversed char array prints both the output and input?

Tags: arrays, c, char, reverse

Trying to input a 2 digit number e.g '35' and have the output return '53', however, my code makes it so that the output is '5335' rather than just '53' im completely lost and have been hunting for previous answers for hours to no success.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char input[2];
    char output[2];
    int length;

    printf("Enter a two-digit positive integer: ");
    scanf("%s", input);

    length = sizeof(input);

    int x = 0;

    while(length >=0) {
        length--;
        output[x]=input[length];
        printf("%s", output);
        x++;
    }
    printf("The reversed number is: %s", output);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: `input` and `output` should be at least `3` `char`s because it must be `NUL` terminated to print properly.  Try this `char input[3] = {0}; char output[3] = {0}`.

Comment: You're writing past the end of `input`, corrupting memory and invoking undefined behavior.  And you aren't null-terminating `output`.  So you can't print it as a string without again invoking undefined behavior.  You should take some time to learn about arrays, pointers, and strings.

Comment: Also, for safety, check the return value of `scanf` (so you know if you actually got anything), and use `%2s`, not plain `%s` in your `scanf` (or it will accept an arbitrary number of characters into your buffer that can only hold `2`, once you expand them per Fiddling Bits's recommendation).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things that needs to be changed in the code.

1. The char array length must be 3 in this case as your char ararys are supposed to store 2 characters. (One extra character for the null-terminating character '\0')
2. The length variable will store the number of bytes occupied by the character array but not the number of characters in the array. You might consider doing

   length = sizeof(input)/sizeof(char)
3. Doing the modifications as mentioned in 1st and 2nd points will still result in an invalid result because the first thing you are appending to the input is the last character which will be '\0' and the output will always be an empty string. You should start appending from the 2nd last character of the input string and finally append a null-terminating character in the output.

Note:- It would be great if you can brush up on your knowledge of fundamental concepts of C.